Error en impresion en lenguaje C con codigo modular
Tengo error con mi código al imprimir la opción 1 ya que no imprime igual que el ejemplo propocionado en el pfd (adjuntos fotos del problema), adjunto mi código para que me puedan ayudar o dar ejemplos intente con for o do while o incluso poniendo en fila no se cual es mi error me podrian ayudar por favor y cada uno de los codigos modulares que utilice :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
int generaAleatorio(int,int);
void imprimeLinea(int,char);
void imprimeFigura(int);
float calcularSumatoria(int);
int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int opcion,genera,cantidad,n,imprimir,imprimirLinea;
    float resultado;
    char caracter='@';
    do{
        printf("Opciones:\n");
        printf("1.- Imprime Figura.\n");
        printf("2.- Calcula Sumatoria.\n");
        printf("Ingrese la opción a elegir (1 o 2): ");
        scanf("%i", &opcion);
        if (opcion == 1) {
            genera= generaAleatorio(10, 55);
            imprimeLinea(cantidad,'@');
            imprimeFigura(genera);
        } else if (opcion == 2) {
            n=generaAleatorio(8, 22);
            resultado = calcularSumatoria(n);
            printf("Sumatoria resultante para los %i terminos: %.3f\n", n, resultado);
        } else {
            printf("Opción inválida. Por favor, ingrese 1 o 2.\n");
        }
    }while(opcion!=1 &&opcion!=2);
    return 0;
}

int generaAleatorio(int x,int y){
    int r;
    r=rand()%(y-x+1)+x;
    return x;
}

void imprimeFigura(int genera){
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < genera; i++) {
        imprimeLinea(genera, 'H');
    }
}

void imprimeLinea(int cantidad, char caracter) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
        printf("%c ", caracter);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

float calcularSumatoria(int n){
    int i;
    float sumatoria=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        sumatoria=sumatoria+(sin(i)*sin(i))/(pow(i,2.6)+0.8);
    }
    return sumatoria;
}

imagen de los datos


[![ejemplo opcion2][5]][5]



Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Si tu problema es solo con la opción 2, no hace falta ni tanto código, ni tanta imagen. Un [mcve] tendría solo la rutina que imprime la imagen y un ejemplo de lo que se quiere lograr (en texto, no en imagenes).

@jachguate es que queria subirlo todo como un forma de mostrar como lo hice pero en si mi problema es con la opcion 1 no con la 2

Es lo mismo, tu pregunta va a ser mejor entendida si publicas un [mcve]. Además, las descripciones y ejemplos, en texto, no en imagenes.

@jachguate ya lo edite perdon es mi primera vez pregutando pense q era toda la infromacion para q se entienda

Estos ejercicios del primer curso de programación están diseñados para desarrollar la lógica del programador.
En este caso, la idea es que hagas el esfuerzo mental por entender cómo lograr la figura que se espera y seas capaz de abstraer esa idea hasta expresarla en código de un lenguaje de programación.
Si observas la salida que genera tu programa, puedes ir encontrando dónde están las fallas en tu lógica.
Lo que yo puedo comentar es que, en cada línea necesitas saber la línea en la que estás para poder imprimirla.
Supongamos que debes imprimir una figura de 10 x 10. Esto significa que cada línea tiene que tener 10 caracteres y debes imprimir 10 líneas.
En la línea 0, necesitas imprimir 9 veces el caracter @ y una vez el H
En la línea 1, 8 veces el @ y 2 el H
Si hacemos una tablita, se vería así:



línea
@
H
Total(n)




0
9
1
10


1
8
2
10


2
7
3
10


3
6
4
10


4
5
5
10


5
4
6
10


6
3
7
10


7
2
8
10


8
1
9
10


9
0
10
10



Veamos una de 3x3



línea
@
H
Total(n)




0
2
1
3


1
1
2
3


2
0
3
3



¿Notas que va emergiendo un patrón?
Ahora, una vez comprendes el patrón, toca pensar cómo lograr hacer ciclos que lleguen a esos límites que nos permitan ir imprimiendo caracter por caracter, de manera similar a lo que ya haces.
Para hacerlo de manera general, esto implica deducir la fórmula que nos lleve al número que queremos.
Por ejemplo, si sabemos n y el número de la línea, podemos llegar al número de @ con la fórmula n - (linea + 1)
Probemos la fórmula, para la línea 4, cuando n es 10, nos daría 10 - (4 + 1) es decir 5, que es justamente la cantidad de caracteres que tenemos que imprimir.
La cantidad de H's es más fácil, pues es línea + 1.
Con esto, ya habrás identificado que para imprimir cada línea, hay que hacer dos ciclos, uno para imprimir n - (linea + 1) veces el caracter @ y otro para imprimir linea + 1 veces el caracter H.
Ya con este análisis, si dominas la sintaxis del lenguaje, debiera resultar bastante natural escribir el código.
Te dejo el ejemplo resuelto, pero te sugiero no verlo, menos copiarlo y pegarlo, sino en este punto, ir a tu editor y tratar de resolverlo por ti mismo. Si no te funciona, vuelve a leer la respuesta, haz tus ejercicios en papel, hasta lograr corregir el algorítmo.
Luego, solo por diversión, puedes ver que tan distinto de este quedó.
#include <stdio.h>

void imprimirFigura(int n) {
    for (int linea = 0; linea < n; linea++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n - (linea + 1); i++) {
            printf("@");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < (linea + 1); i ++) {
            printf("H");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    // Write C code here
    imprimirFigura(10);
    printf("\n");
    imprimirFigura(25);
    return 0;
}

Posdata: La idea es que, para los próximos ejercicios, hagas tu el esfuerzo de comprenderlo hasta lograr expresarlo en código. He hecho yo este ejercicio con la intención de mostrarte el camino, pero esta ya es una bala perdida, pues ahora no puedes aprovecharlo para en realidad aprender a programar, que es ese proceso de mental de comprender y darle vueltas hasta encontrar el camino para expresarlo en código. Espero hacerte más bien que mal al haberlo hecho por tí esta vez.

@jachgaute gracias entinedo q la importancia es resolver hasta esta parte del curso me fue facil claro por q era lo basico pero ahora q se complica entre comilla debo buscar mi forma de saber resolver y mediante practica igual practicare antes de ver y si puede hacerlo de otra forma para q mi mente se quede con un proceso facil para resolver en proximos ejercicios lo hare gracias
